# Приведение к интерфейсу

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Есть класс. Предположим, что у него есть определенные свойства, методы, события.

Но ко мне он приходит в виде object. Приводить его к конкретному типу не хочется, использовать динамик тоже. Зато я знаю, что у него есть метод `DoWork()`. Хотелось бы привести его к интерфейсу

```
IMyInterface
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

Есть ли способ проще чем прокси?

Comment: Если класс интерфейс реализует - приводите. А при чем тут прокси и в каком виде?

Comment: @Monk, а если не реализует? Но я точно знаю, что там есть определенные методы.

Comment: для таких случаев как раз динамик

Comment: А почему вы не хотите сделать так как *правильно*?

Comment: А чем вам dinamic не подходит?

Comment: @iRumba к сожалению, .net не поддерживает утиную типизацию в этом случае.

Comment: Можете посмотреть решение: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/122827/DynamicObjects-Duck-Typing-in-NET

Comment: На случай, если приходит реально один тип, можно рефлекшном разок достать и закешировать methodinfo или как его там.

Comment: @SeeSharp не нравится мне, во что он разворачивается во время компиляции.

Comment: @Ares, поэтому я и спрашиваю про способы обхода.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, потому что MyClass мне не доступен. Нет референса

Comment: @iRumba интересно... А вам я так понял нужно достать до метода `DoWork`?

Comment: Ну тогда остается, как выше предлагают, достать рефлексией и, если надо часто вызывать, создать делегат

Comment: Еще как вариант, сделать обертку под Ваш класс (если есть возможность унаследоваться) + адаптер.

Comment: @Ares, так вышло, что у меня нет референса на сборку с этим классом

Comment: @Monk dynamic будет работать быстрее чем "разок закешированный" methodinfo

Comment: @iRumba сначала вы спрашиваете "есть ли способ проще, чем прокси", а теперь выясняется что вам этот самый прокси-то и не подходит. Пожалуйста, уточните на какой из двух вопросов вам нужен ответ - на исходный (и тогда ответ будет "нет, используйте прокси") или на более сложный.

Comment: я вообще не могу понять зачем такие танцы с бубном)